# Spawning Sprites In Space Invaders

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently trying to spawn aliens for a space invaders game I'm creating in class. I'm using a while loop with a counter to adjust an array to a given variable value. This way I can increase the number of aliens without any re-writing. The problem is, although my aliens spawn, the x position is not increasing as I would like it to. I only see one Alien on the screen so I've concluded that they are all spawning, but only with a 1-pixel difference, therefore unnoticeable. Here's what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Add and display given amount of aliens...
    while (alienAmount > displayLoopCounter) {
        aliens.append(SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ClassicAlien")))
        self.addChild(aliens[displayLoopCounter])
        //Location
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.y = CGFloat(-15)
        aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x = CGFloat(displayLoopCounter + 25)
        print(aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x)
        displayLoopCounter += 1
        print(displayLoopCounter)
       //Have we run out of aliens yet?
        if displayLoopCounter > alienAmount {
            displayAliens = false
}
```

Comment: There is a great tutorial on RayWenderlich.com that show how to make a game like space invaders. It may be beneficial to you! https://www.raywenderlich.com/124005/make-game-like-space-invaders-sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the spacing you're setting between aliens. In other terms, you need to set the `x` position of each alien sprite to have more spacing between them. Currently, you are just adding `displayLoopCounter` to the `x` position of each alien. Since `displayLoopCounter` only increases one at a time, the aliens are all spawned with a 1-pixel difference to each other. If we want a bigger difference, we will need to multiply `displayLoopCounter` by our intended spacing so that we get that spacing between each alien.

You can just set a `spacingBetweenAliens` variable with a numeric type (such as `Int` or `CGFLoat` or `Double`) and change this line:

```
aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x = CGFloat(displayLoopCounter + 25)
```

To this:

```
let basePosition = displayLoopCounter * spacingBetweenAliens
aliens[displayLoopCounter].position.x = CGFloat(basePosition + 25)
```

This way, the aliens will be spawned with the value of  `spacingBetweenAliens` in pixels between them.

Comment: Thanks! This was a big help!